# How Can I Make A Password Protected Page In JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, authentication

Example code:

```
Password:<br>
<input type="password" name="password" id="thePassword"><br>
<button onclick="checkPassword();">Enter</button>
```

And:

```
    function checkPassword() {
    var pwd = document.getElementById("thePassword");
    if (pwd.value=="admin") {
        window.location.href="http://localhost/admin.html";
    } else {
       alert("INCORRECT PASSWORD!");
    }
}
```

Can this successfully work? (I know that it is insecure) (I don't have a server set up yet)

Comment: Yeah. But when I see the source code I will know the password. Cool!

Comment: Yes it will work.   Please send me the URL of the website implementing this robust security so that I can use and abuse it.

Comment: LOL. I know that you will see the password in the source code. I'm just making sure.

Comment: Simple answer is ... you can't do user authorization in the browser alone without server interaction

Comment: @YoungCoder: If you have to do it client-side, compare password hashes instead (PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt), but your security will still be merely non-zero. You **have to** do it server-side.

Comment: *"Can this successfully work?"* Why don't you test it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

This will work but is insecure.

All your Javascript code can be seen by the user. You have to send the password to your server to check it, and the server needs to check if your user is authenticated either by a cookie or a token before sending any data to the user.

Comment: Thanks Lux! I'm working on setting up my server-authenticator.

Answer (score -1):

Making a password protected page in JavaScript is easy. You can use JavaScript on the server via [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and there you can check your login for correct input.

Do not enforce your security policy on the client only, as creative attackers can write their own clients.